# Prevent text overflow in nested row/column widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a sample layout as following:

1. 3 containers of fixed size (red, blue, green, container labels are `height x width`)
2. a text widget that may have variable size (based on the text content):

[image]

The overall height of the widget is `300px`. The layout is roughly as follows:

```
Row(
    [
        red,
        Column(
            [
                Row([green, text]),
                Spacer(),
                blue,
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
```

The problem is if I increase the text length, it overflows the screen as follows:

[image]

The text has already been styled to be `maxLines:1` and `overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis`. Moreover, I have tried adding `Expanded` at various levels (to the text widget, to the row containing it, to the column containing it, to the overall outer box), but no avail.

Can you please suggest how to go about this?

Here's the source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Container getContainer({h, w, color}) => Container(
        color: color,
        height: h,
        width: w,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            '$h x $w',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      );

  Text getText(text) => Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 1,
      );

  Widget applyBorder(widget) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
        child: widget,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double overallHeight = 300;

    var red = getContainer(h: overallHeight, w: 150, color: Colors.red);
    var green = getContainer(h: 100, w: 60, color: Colors.green);
    var blue = getContainer(h: 100, w: 150, color: Colors.blue);
    var text = getText('hello! ' * 10);

    Widget row1 = Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [green, text],
    );
    row1 = applyBorder(row1);

    Widget col1 = Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [row1, Spacer(), blue],
    );
    col1 = applyBorder(col1);
    col1 = SizedBox(height: overallHeight, child: col1);

    Widget row2 = Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [red, col1],
    );
    row2 = applyBorder(row2);

    return row2;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try wrapping your Text widget with Wrap widget or place it in a SizedBox and assign Custom width

Comment: @Prashant: Wrapping it inside `Wrap` or `Expanded` doesn't work. I can't assign custom width since I may not know it beforehand. The red container may also shrink expand based on user data. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the text with a flexible widget and add overflow if required

```dart
Flexible(
 child: Text(
  "Some big text here",
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  maxLines : 3//add any max line here
 )
)
```

Also wrap the col1's column widget with a flexible so the row gets its bounds

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap col1's column also in a flexible

Comment: Thanks that does work (wrapping `text` and `col1` inside `Expanded`). Care to explain why this work? Thanks!

Comment: You had a row - column then again a row. The text in inside the last row. The column has no horizontal bound. So additing a flexible to column made sure that it is bound to the end of the screen the row also is bound till that extent so the text overflow worked

Comment: Please edit your answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247030/discussion-between-abhinavkulkarni-and-kaushik-chandru).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Row` with `Flexible`:

```
Widget row1 = Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [green, Flexible(child: text)],
    );

Widget row2 = Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [red, Flexible(child: col1)],
    );
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text into flexible widget and then try to expand some of its properties

```
    Flexible(
     child: Text(
      'Your text...!',
     )
    )
```